# How can I access parent model fields in a form using the child model?

Tags: django

For context, I'm trying to create a form that allows users to upload info about their own custom Pokemon. Basically, they are creatures that you can catch, name, and level up. To draw a comparison, it is a similar concept to dogs; there are labradors, German Shepherds, huskies, etc. that would be variations of a base Dog model, but then each individual would have a name and other defining characteristics.

I've created Pokemon and CustomPokemon models and imported the latter into my forms.py file. I'm trying to access some parent fields but am unable to:

```
from django import forms

from .models import CustomPokemon

class PokemonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomPokemon
        fields = ['pokemon.poke_name', 'name', 'level']
```

The poke_name field is inherited from the parent `Pokemon` model while the other two fields belong to the `CustomPokemon` model. I'm getting this FieldError:

`Unknown field(s) (pokemon.poke_name) specified for CustomPokemon.`

The issue isn't resolved by using `poke_name`, so I'm curious how I can access the parent model's fields so they can be displayed in the form.

Comment: Can you add your Model code for `CustomPokemon` in your post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First option

If you just want a dropdown displaying the field `poke_name`, what you could do is to define a `__str__` method inside `Pokemon` model like this:

```
class Pokemon(model.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.poke_name
```

Then, you can define the form as follows:

```
class PokemonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomPokemon
        fields = ['pokemon', 'name', 'level']
```

And you will get a dropdown displaying all the `poke_name` of your database, where you can choose your foreign key. It would be better if `poke_name` is a `unique` field so that the foreign key can be clearly identified.

## Second option

If you need more freedom, you could manually define a custom field as follows:

```
class PokemonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    poke_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomPokemon
        fields = ['name', 'level']
```

Then, when validating the form, you should take care of whether the entry exists and/or create it:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.pokemon = Pokemon.objects.get_or_create(cname=form.cleaned_data['poke_name'])
    form.save()
```